# ADB over Wifi when PC is connected to LAN and Mobile to Wifi, on same Network

Tags: android, networking, adb, adbwireless

I know how to connect `adb` over wifi when both computer and smartphone are on same Wifi Network.

But can I connect `adb` over wifi when Computer is connected to LAN and Smartphone to Wifi, on same network.

I am using UBUNTU.

Comment: have you tried this? https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001546/task/android/t_faq_connect_with_adb_android.htm

Comment: and this https://community.nxp.com/thread/300323